# Removing text of NamedRange leaves an empty paragraph on the line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to delete all the name ranges from google doc, but when i delete them using the following code the text and namedRanges are deleted by it leaves an empty paragraph at the place of each namedRange.

```
nameRanges.forEach(function (rangeEntry) {
    var ele = rangeEntry.getRange().getRangeElements()[0];
    var sOffset = ele.getStartOffset();
    var eOffset = ele.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var txtObj = ele.getElement().asText();
    txtObj.deleteText(sOffset, eOffset);
    rangeEntry.remove();
}
```

i am accessing the paragraphs using below code, and their text property is returning as empty string.

```
body.getParagraphs().forEach( function (para, ind) {             
    console.log('para', para.editAsText().getText());             
})
```

How can i delete nameRange so it doesn't leave anything behind?
Thanks

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to delete all named ranges.
- You want to also delete the paragraphs which has the named ranges, while the named ranges are deleted.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used `removeFromParent()`. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification point:

- Retrieve the parent of the element from `var ele = rangeEntry.getRange().getRangeElements()[0]`. Then, the parent is removed by `removeFromParent()`.

#### Modified script:

```
nameRanges.forEach(function (rangeEntry) {
  var ele = rangeEntry.getRange().getRangeElements()[0];

  var parent = ele.getElement().getParent(); // Added
  parent.removeFromParent(); // Added

  rangeEntry.remove();
});
```

- By the way, when `clear()` is used instead of `removeFromParent()`, I think that the result is the same with your current script.

#### References:

- [getParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#getparent)
- [removeFromParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#removefromparent)
- [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#clear)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Document you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm your situation. Of course, please remove your personal information from the sample Document.

Comment: thanks for giving such a detailed answer, your code is giving me "Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section" error.

Comment: Your understanding is correct i want to delete the namedRange along with it's containing paragraph.

Comment: @Haris Jamil Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I would like to confirm your situation. So can you provide the sample Document you want to use? Of course, please remove your personal information from the sample Document.